# Erro ao tentar conectar banco de dados Mysql ao eclipse utilizando JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

Eu já tentei algumas soluções, já reinstalei o Mysql e o Workbench, mas parece não aceitar a minha senha. Simplesmente continua dando o mesmo erro. Obs.: eu não alterei o nome do usuário no banco, deixei como padrão. Isto está acontecendo depois de eu tentar executar essa classe:

```
public class Conexao {
         public static final String SERVIDOR = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdJava";
         public static final String USUARIO = "root";
         public static final String SENHA = "123456";
         
         public Connection getConexao() {
             try {
                 return DriverManager.getConnection(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA);
                     
           }catch (Exception e) {
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
             }
      } }
```

Erro apresentado no console:

> Exceção no thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Acesso negado para o
> usuário '' @ 'localhost' (usando a senha: NÃO) em
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException
> (SQLError.java:129) em
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException
> (SQLError.java:97) em
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException
> (SQLExceptionsMapping.java.jdbcl) em
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException
> (SQLExceptionsMapping.cjava.jdbcl. ConnectionImpl.createNewIO
> (ConnectionImpl.java:836) em com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.
> (ConnectionImpl.java:456) em
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance (ConnectionImpl.java:246)
> em com. mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect
> (NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) em
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection (fonte desconhecida) em
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection (fonte desconhecida) em
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin .TimezoneDump.main (TimezoneDump.java:70)

ao tentar trocar a senha da conexão do banco o erro persiste. há um erro peculiar que me chamou a atenção, erro: Exceção no thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Acesso negado para o usuário '' @ 'localhost' (usando senha: NÃO), aparece que o usuário está vazio, porém o usuário do meu banco está o padrão, que seria 'root'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos criar uma conexão utilizando o Mysql, a primeira coisa que precisa verificar é se seu banco está ativo, como está utilizando o mysql você pode utilizar um software ou mesmo o terminal de seu computador para fazer isso, um software bem conhecido é o https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ antes de sair codificando é imprescindível verificar esse ponto.

Agora que já verificou que seu banco de dados está funcionando perfeitamente e você sabe qual é a porta que ele está utilizando (Ps. geralmente Mysql é a 3306) tenha certeza que você vai precisar de um driver de conexão e nesse caso o do próprio Mysql, esses drivers nada mais são do que bibliotecas que poderão ser utilizadas no projeto, você precisa saber como seu projeto irá armazenar essas libs, caso ele esteja utilizando https://maven.apache.org/ você precisa adicionar ela ao seu pom.xml, perceba que você precisa saber qual é a versão de seu banco de dados para ter a compatibilidade e funcionar, nesse link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java tem as versões para baixar, caso o projeto seja um projeto comum no eclipse basta baixar o **jar** e adicionar a dependência ao projeto, clicando com botão direito em cima do projeto indo até o sub menu build path e adicionando um jar externo, o mesmo arquivo que foi baixado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após esses passos é preciso começar a pensar na forma de implementarmos a conexão:

```
 public class Conexao {
         public static final String SERVIDOR = 
         "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdJava";
         public static final String USUARIO = "root";
         public static final String SENHA = "123456";
         
         public Connection getConexao() {
             try {
                 return DriverManager.getConnection(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA);
                     
           }catch (Exception e) {
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
             }
      } }
```

nesse ponto ficou faltando a porta:

```
   "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdJava";
```

um exemplo de conexão poderia ser:

```
private Conexao() {
    try {
        String driverName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        String serverName = "127.0.0.1:3306";
        String mydatabase = "bdJava";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase + "?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "123456";

        this.connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Nao foi possivel encontrar o driver: " + e.toString());
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Nao foi possivel conectar ao banco de dados: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Outro assunto que precisa observar é quanto a conexão de dados remotos no mysql 8, nesse link tem uma descrição em **inglês** de como resolver.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12844804/2829667

Ps. Uma conexão utilizando JDBC sem nenhuma implementação de JPA não é mais comun em novos projetos hoje em dia, no link a baixo há um projeto que consta uma classe de conexão onde há alguns comportamentos que uma classe conexão utilizando JDBC pode ter.
https://github.com/andremartds/JDBC_revisao/tree/main/src